# Install Perl modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to migrate a code from Linux to Windows 7. I use MinGW to run perl. Regarding this code I need to install 'Clone 0.31', 'Data-Dumper 2.121', Hash-Merge 0.11' and 'threads 1.71' packages. But, the version of these packages that I have are good for Linux. I wonder if there is a Windows version available for those modules.

Comment: what type and version of windows perl?

Comment: perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int

Comment: What is the reason you aren't going up to at least 5.8.9?

Comment: What makes you think they won't work on Windows?

Comment: @ikegami: "packages" makes me think s/he is talking about rpm/deb/etc

Comment: because I tried to compile them but compilation is terminated

Comment: Let me phrase that differently: You can install those modules in Windows. In fact, threads and Data::Dumper come with Perl!

Comment: @user2166951 Could you add the errors you're encountering to your post?  Then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use that specific Perl on Windows, I would suggest updating to [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  Its a bundled Perl environment including gcc, C libraries needed by common Perl modules, and commonly used database drivers.  It includes a configured CPAN shell, accessible from the Start menu, for installing modules.

That is the easiest way to use Perl and install modules on Windows.

Otherwise, the modules you mention *should* compile on Windows, but without seeing specific error messages we can't help you with your problem.